# API's does not run when run command gradle build

Tags: java, api, gradle, automation, build.gradle

I am working on API automation where I have used rest assured and Gradle for my build. 
When I run the command Gradle build in terminal it not run my API which is declared in the main class.

my build.gradle my is as follows

```
  plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir "src/main"
    main.resources.srcDir "src/main/resources"
}
group 'com.API_AUTO'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured:3.0.0'
    //compile "io.rest-assured, name: rest-assured, version: 3.0.2"
    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.10'
    compile group: 'org.apache.poi', name: 'poi-ooxml', version: '3.15'
    compile group: 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi', name: 'jxl', version: '2.6.12'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.6'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.htmlcompressor', name: 'htmlcompressor', version: '1.5.2'
    compile group: 'commons-dbutils', name: 'commons-dbutils', version: '1.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-databind', version: '2.8.6'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'
    compile group: "com.github.fge", name: "json-schema-validator", version: "2.2.6"
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20160810'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.4'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.guice-repository', name: 'guice-repository', version: '2.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.easytesting', name: 'fest-assert-core', version: '2.0M10'
    compile group: 'org.uncommons', name: 'reportng', version: '1.1.4'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-csv', version: '1.5'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-exec', version: '1.3'
    compile group: 'com.opencsv', name: 'opencsv', version: '4.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.0'
    testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.1'
    compile 'com.relevantcodes:extentreports:2.41.2'
    compile group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.0'
    compile 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2'
    compile 'com.sun.mail:smtp:1.6.2'
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'javax.mail-api', version: '1.6.2'

}
/*jar {
    from('src/main/java') {
        include 'resource/extent-config.xml'
        include 'resource/config.properties'
    }
    from configurations.compile.collect { zipTree it }
    manifest.attributes "Main-Class": "com.xxxx.yyy.mainRunner"
}*/

configurations {
    cucumberRuntime {
        extendsFrom testRuntime
    }
}

task cucumber() {
    dependsOn assemble, compileTestJava
    doLast {
        javaexec {
            main = "com.xxxx.yyy.mainRunner"
            classpath = configurations.cucumberRuntime + sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        }
    }
}
```

Then my mainclass is as follows-

```
    import Api_Test_Scripts.RunnerSub;

public class mainRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        RunnerSub obj= new RunnerSub();
        obj.starttest();
        obj.runner();
        obj.endReport();
    }
}
```

My expectation here is when I run the command Gradle build in terminal it should start executing the API.

Comment: you may want to read up on a few basics. an api and an entry point for an application are not the same. You also don't seem to know about naming conventions. Now this: why do you want this main method to be triggered by build, and how do you know it doesn't run?

Comment: @Stultuske I know it is not running because i have added logs and which not coming while running the API by command Gradle build where as same when I do with IntelliJ it does show me the logs. Also I want to run it from the main because then it will create a jar which can be run also. Without main cannot create a jar. My only expected result is when i run the command Gradle build it should start running the API's.

Comment: you have added logs ... not according to the code you posted. It is very well possible your IntelliJ run uses other properties than your Gradle build, so don't consider that to be the "ultimate proof". But still, build is supposed to build your application, not run it.

Comment: Not helping me. Still thanks for your time. @Stultuske

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found and fixed this issue.
There are two methods as follows-

1. Basically I was trying to run the API's or you can say classes which are in main folder through build.gradle where as to perform this action.

We should have both test folder and main folder structure which basically have the test methods which invokes the main folder classes with the respective codes.

I made this below changes voila! it worked as my gradle.build was running by test defined in it.

[image: Runner file which invokes the main]

gradle.build file changes-

```
test {
    reports {
        junitXml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = false
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("test-output/reports/")
    }
    useTestNG()
            {
                useDefaultListeners = true
                options.suites("src/test/java/testApi_Test_Scripts/smsApiAutomationSuite.xml")
                options.listeners << 'com.kaleyra.smsApi.qa.framework.listener.CustomListener'
                //options.listeners << 'com.kaleyra.smsApi.qa.framework.listener.EmailListener'
                //options.listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter'
                options.listeners << 'org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter'
                systemProperty 'org.uncommons.reportng.title', 'sms_api_automation_results'

            }
    testLogging.events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    testLogging.exceptionFormat = "full"
```

2. Add this in your build.gradle-

   apply plugin:'application'
   mainClassName = "com.XXXX.smsApi.qa.framework.mainRunner"

And viola!

If you ask me which option is better than I will choose the first one.